# Autostart python programm

Tags: raspbian, python

i prefer ask you that i'm French ^^
So I will be very simple.

I would like, when i start my raspberry a execution of my python file.
That is to says, I want that when my pi starting the programm is running (and we can see on desktop so we can directly respond to a input )

I don't know if you arrived to understand what I said.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy answer: that's normal, you're starting the "idle" file editor.
Correct display.desktop file would be:

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=exe
Exec=python /home/admin/Desktop/exe.py`

French version:
C'est normal, on appelle l'éditeur au lieu de python!
Voir ci-dessus la version corrigée du fichier ^^

Comment: Of course, this supposes Python is in your PATH environment variable, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that :

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/display.desktop
```

and edit the file with :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=exe
Exec=/usr/bin/idle /home/admin/Desktop/exe.py
```

But when my pi starts, it's just launch the edition of the file ^^ not the running

Comment: No it's didn't work !
Because it's just starting with the python file edit.

Comment: You're not supposed to post answers like that. I understand that you're French and new to this platform, but just saying, If you want to exclaim something, comment it under the answer from someone else, instead of posting an answer.